# Call event when performing another action

Tags: jquery

This is action performed when I click on button:

```
$('div.my-button').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
        // some code
});
```

How can I call this event when performing another action, e.g. on keypress? Should I move code of this event to separate function or I can call a click or something?

I tried to call click:

```
$('div.my-button').click()
```

but the action was not performed.

I use jquery 1.9+

EDIT 1:

```
    $('div.my-button').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/my_url/",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "value": $this.val(),
            },
            success: function(result){
                //some actions
            },
            error: function(result){
                //some actions
            }
        });
    });
```

I try to call this using:

```
    jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 's',function (e){
        $('div.my-button').trigger('click');
    });
```

For binding keys i use [jquery.hotkey](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/README.md)

.trigger does not work for me.

Comment: You should show us the whole code, because `$( selector ).click()`is a shortcut for `$( selector ).trigger('click')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) as you may not want the default click behaviour or event propagation to happen

```
$('div.my-button button').triggerHandler('click') ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div.my-button').trigger('click') ;
```

Answer (score 2):

use [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)...

> Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the .trigger() method. A call to .trigger() executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user:

```
$('div.my-button button').trigger('click') ;
```